# how to obtain the implicits equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to solve the following problem

In $\mathbb{R}^3$ we consider the linear system :

$L_1 = \{ (x,y,z) = (1,0,-1) + U_1\}$

$U_1=\{(1,0,1),(0,1,-2)\}$

It is required to find implicit equations of $L_1.$

Until now I have done the following:

I use Gaussian elimination with the matrix $L_1$ , to obtain linear independency .

Now to find the implicit equation I have :

$$(x,y,z) = A(1, 0, -1) + B(1, 0, 1) + C(0, 1, -2)$$

And the system is :

x=A + B

y= C

z=-A+B-2C

and then I pass A,B and C to the other side

A=x-B

B=(-x-2y-z)/2

C = y

What do I have to do now to obtain the implicit equations ?

PS: I will appreciate if someone explains a general way to obtain it.

Comment: really no one can help me?